# Getting "Warning: setState(...): Can only update a mounted or mounting component." error when setting state inside "FB.Event.subscribe()" function

Tags: javascript, facebook, reactjs

I am trying to add Facebook login on my page using the Facebook API. When the user clicks on the *Login with Facebook* button I want the page to redirect to another. To do this I have done the following:

```
componentDidMount() {
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId            : '1947842912095857',
      autoLogAppEvents : true,
      xfbml            : true,
      version          : 'v2.10'
    });
    FB.AppEvents.logPageView();
    FB.getLoginStatus((response) => {
      if (response.status === 'connected') {
        console.log('Logged in.');
        this.setState({ loggedIn: true });
      }
      else {
      }
    });

  // login callback implementation goes inside the function() { ... } block
  FB.Event.subscribe('auth.statusChange', (response) => {
    if (response.authResponse) {
      console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
      FB.api('/me', (response) => {
        console.log('Good to see you, ' + response.name + '.');
        this.setState({ loggedIn: true });
        // if(!this.state.loggedIn){
        // }
      });
    } else {
      console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
    }
  });
}.bind(this);
  (function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

    var s = '<div class="fb-login-button" ' +
        'data-scope="public_profile,email" data-size="large" ' +
        'data-show-faces="false" data-auto-logout-link="true" ' +
        'href="javascript:void(0)""></div>';

    var div = document.getElementById('social-login-button-facebook')
    div.innerHTML = s;
}
```

First I initialize the Facebook API. Then I call `FB.getLoginStatus()` to see if the user is already logged in. In the callback I set the `this.state.loggedIn` to `true` and it works fine. However, in the `FB.Event.subscribe()` function when I call the `this.setState` function I get the following error:

```
Warning: setState(...): Can only update a mounted or mounting component.
```

I tried to solve this and the solution I tried was to check if the user was **not** already logged in and then set the state.

```
if(!this.state.loggedIn){
  this.setState({ loggedIn: true });
}
```

Then I got rid of the error. But I don't know why that is. 
Does anyone know why it works to call `this.setState()` in `FB.getLoginStatus()` but not in `FB.Event.subscribe()` and why it only works to set state if the user is not already logged in?

Thanks for taking your time and reading this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has to do with the asynchronous nature of the request. While the component may be mounted at some point, if there is a pending request that does not finish until after the component is unmounted, then you will be trying to `setState` on an unmounted component.

For example:

```
class LoginComponent extends Component {

    componentWillMount() {
        // This request will happen whenever the component mounts
        Request.get('/login-token').then(() => {
            dispatch({type: SET_TOKEN, token: 'blah blah'});

            // Whoops, what if there was already a login token 
            // and the user was redirected? This will attempt to set
            // state on a component that has been unmounted due to redirect
            this.setState({loggedIn: true});
        });
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(props) {
        // This will only redirect if there is already a token
        if (props.token) {
           browserHistory.push('/some-logged-in-page');
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            // ...
        );
    }
}
```

In this example, a request will try to get a token every time the component mounts. But we are checking if a token is passed in via props, and potentially redirecting. Due to the async nature of the request, if there is a token that is passed in, and the user is redirected, the request will still complete and try to `setState`, but the component will have already been unmounted by then.

Check out this [react blog post](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/12/16/ismounted-antipattern.html) which talks about issues dealing with async requests, and proposes methods to safely cancel requests in componentWillUnmount.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. Now I understand why checking the state before setting it works.